# Bootstrap - Grid system - Fixed height issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I building a web application using the Bootstrap grid system as my layout. So far everything was working great but got into this issue where I have a div row that has a large image (width 1280px by height 150 px) and when you resize the page the image overlaps over divs.

To fix that I put a fixed height (height 150px) on my div and it stopped resizing and overlapping but I introduced a new problem. This nows throws off my layout and adds a vertical scrolling bar and I need my web app to fit the entire page only.

I was thinking of maybe adding a overflow: hidden to my CSS but seems a bit hacky to me. Just looking for advice and maybe a different approach to my layout. It seems that Bootstrap dosent play nice with fixed heights.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9847/

```
<div class="container-fluid row-fluid" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="row grey" style="height: 10%;"> title of the website here </div>
    <div class="row yellow" style="height: 150px; text-align: center;"> 
        <img width="1280px" height="150px" src="https://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4n498M3NQ1r9f8g8o1_1280.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="row grey" style="height: 60%;"> main content area </div>
    <div class="row grey" style="height: 10%;"> footer area </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using bootstrap is not correct. Your are not manipulating bootstrap grid system properly. Your have put your image in a row but not in a column. You know you should have minimum one column(e.g. `col-md-12`) in a row. Then Bootstrap will consider your image or content perfectly. Refactor your code and follow the way bootstrap told you to do. Besides, you can make your image responsive using bootstrap's `img-responsive` class. See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Comment: Thanks man its starting to make alot of sense now, I was missing a column in each of my rows. Things are starting to fit in place now. Thanks you so much.

Comment: You are most welcome. Don't forget to vote my answer up. Best of luck (y)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this. This basically applies **max-width: 100%; height: auto; and display: block;** to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

```
    <img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

You can read more at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/qxLtmhat/

Answer (score 0):

First you know you should have minimum one column(e.g. col-md-12 in a row) - see the first answer from Imran and second you hard coded the width and height - remove them and add the img-responsive class on the img.